# jQuery Flask POST : 405 Method not allowed

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, post, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a form and when I can add new element in my db but they is error and I have new page with this error :

**Method Not Allowed
The method is not allowed for the requested URL.**

In console : POST http://localhost:5000/ [HTTP/1.0 405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED 2ms]

**My form :**

```
<form method="POST" id="formsondages" name="formsondages" style="text-align:center;"> 
    <div style="text-align:center;">
        <h4 style="text-align:center;">How ? </h4>
        <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder=" Name...">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="name" style="margin-top:3px;" class="btn btn-success" value="CONFIRM">
</form>
```

**My JS :**

```
$(function(){ 
$('#formsondages').submit(addSondage); 
});

function addSondage(){
    var name = $('#name').val();
    $.post("http://localhost:5000/api/sondages/",{nameS: name});
    sondageActuel = name;
    console.log("It's ok"); 
}
```

**My Server (Flask) :**

```
@app.route('/api/sondages/', methods=['POST'])
def adSondage():
    name = request.form['nameS']
    s = Sondage(name)
    addElement(s)
    return render_template(
    "sondages.html",
        title="Sondages")
```

**My terminal**

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 53759)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 651, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 710, in finish
    self.wfile.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 279, in close
    self.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
```

### **error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe**

```
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Apr/2015 17:25:36] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 - `
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason for you to submit a form using jQuery?

Eliminate the jQuery part, add an "action" into your form and see what'll happen.

Your form should now be:

`<form action="/api/sondages/" method="POST" id="formsondages" name="formsondages" style="text-align:center;">`

Edit: if that's not working, you can add a GET method into your route.

```
@app.route('/api/sondages/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def adSondage():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Put all your POST handling code here
    else:
        return 'GET request successfully'
```